# Moving the absolute value inside of an integral involving a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the following integral to evaluate

$\lvert \int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}e^{iR^2e^{i2\theta}}iRe^{i\theta}d\theta\rvert$

and I want to put the absolute value sign inside of the integral so that I can make some simplifications.

I know that for functions of a real variable $\lvert \int_a^b f(x) dx \rvert \leq \int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert dx $ because of monotonicity of the integral and the fact that $-\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq f(x) \leq \lvert f(x) \rvert$.

But I am having trouble seeing this with functions of a complex value, I know that I am supposed to be able write a similar statement for the integral above, but I'm having trouble with the intuition.

I can't say that $f(z) \leq \lvert f(z) \rvert$ because there is not a total ordering of the complex numbers due to the phase terms, so I'm having trouble justifying moving the absolute value sign inside the integral.

Comment: Well, an integral is a limit of sums, and $|a_1+\cdots+a_n|\le |a_1|+\cdots+|a_n|$...

Comment: With the parametrisation, you have a (complex-valued) function of a real variable that you integrate. Without the parametrisation, the inequality for complex path integrals is $$\biggl\lvert \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz\biggr\rvert \leqslant \int_\gamma \lvert f(z)\rvert\,\lvert dz\rvert,$$ where $\lvert dz\rvert$ is the arc-length measure on the trace of $\gamma$. With a parametrisation, it becomes $\lvert \gamma'(t)\rvert\,dt$.

Comment: The part that I am getting stuck on, and maybe you could elaborate a bit more so I might get it to click, is that if we start with $f(z)dz$ and change to $f(z(t))z'(t)dt$, then we can use the property of absolute values of integrals for real valued functions? Even though the function is still outputting complex values?

Comment: The inequality $\left\lvert \int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right\rvert \leqslant \int_a^b \lvert f(x)\rvert\,dx$ (for $a \leqslant b$) holds not only for real-valued functions but also for complex-valued functions. If you replace the absolute value with a norm, it holds for vector-valued functions (with values in a Banach space). The method of proof differs a little. For complex-valued functions, take an $\alpha$ with $\lvert\alpha\rvert = 1$ so that $\alpha\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \geqslant 0$. Then

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}\left\lvert\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\right\rvert &= \alpha\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\\ &= \int_a^b \alpha f(x)\,dx\\ &= \int_a^b \operatorname{Re} \bigl(\alpha f(x)\bigr)\,dx\\ &\leqslant \int_a^b \bigl\lvert \operatorname{Re}\bigl(\alpha f(x)\bigr)\bigr\rvert\,dx\\ &\leqslant \int_a^b \lvert\alpha f(x)\rvert\,dx\\ &= \int_a^b \lvert f(x)\rvert\,dx. \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks alot! That definitely gives me a better feeling about the statement.